# Insert text around Selection of TextBox control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, selection

I want to insert text around the selection of my `TextBox` control.

I've tried this:

```
if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            object userclipboard = new object();
            userclipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject;
            textBox1.Copy();
            string textCopied = Clipboard.GetTextObject;
            string finalString = "text" + textCopied + "more text";
            textBox1.Paste();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(userclipboard);
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

What im I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see what is happening and what is wrong?

Comment: Its on the error list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Clipboard.GetText()` to paste value from Clipboard and `Clipboard.SetText(finalString);` to copy value

```
string textCopied = Clipboard.GetText();
string finalString = "text" + textCopied + "more text";
Clipboard.SetText(finalString);
textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

if you want to copy the selection text from textbox using the `TextBox` properties

```
string textCopied = textBox1.SelectedText; // To get the selected text from textbox1
string finalString = "text" + textCopied + "more text";
Clipboard.SetText(finalString);
textBox1.Paste();
```

`textBox1.Copy();` will copy you selection text like `Clipboard.SetText(finalString);`